# C# advanced search in list

Tags: c#, list, linq, search

I have in-memory List of strings containing two items: 'product 1 max' and 'product 1 min'. How I can search and get 'product 1 min' when user input is 'product min'?

note there are some missing words in middle.

```
var list = new List<string> {"product 1 max", "product 1 min" };
//user input 'product min' and he expected 'product 1 min'
```

Comment: Are you using LINQ to query against a database or against an in-memory collection?

Comment: in-memory collection

Comment: Take a look at this library https://github.com/softwx/SoftWx.Match, it implements the Damerau-Levenshtein algorithm which calculates how close two strings are from each other.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question, since it now seems clear enough.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias thanks

Comment: @AbdussalamAshuaebi as soon the question reopens I'll post a full answer with an working example

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa I hope that. thanks

Comment: @AbdussalamAshuaebi https://dotnetfiddle.net/TqTmbh fiddle example, hope it helps =)

Comment: It's re-opened now and I upvoted.

Comment: What do you expect if var list = new List<string> {"product 1 max", "product 1 min", "product 2 min" };? Do you need a real search experience with stemming, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the input into words, you can filter the `list` to the matches that contain all the input words:

```
var inputWords = input.Split(' ');
var ans = list.Where(s => inputWords.All(s.Contains)).ToList();
```

NOTE: `s.Contains` is a shorter, more efficient (more obscure) way of doing `w => s.Contains(w)`

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to split the input and match it against each word in the list of strings.

```
var list = new List<string> { "product 1 max", "product 1 min" };
var input = "product min";
List<string> inputParts = input.Split(' ').ToList();

// contains all the input strings
List<string> results = list.Where(x => x.Split(' ').Intersect(inputParts).Count() == inputParts.Count).ToList();

// partial matching strings
List<string> partialMatches = list.Where(x => x.Split(' ').Intersect(inputParts).Count() > 0).ToList();
```

Documentation on the Intersect method can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Your variable x has an error I get this message when I am try to run the code. 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Intersect' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Intersect<string>(IQueryable<string>, IEnumerable<string>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<string>'

Comment: @AbdussalamAshuaebi There was supposed to be a `Split()` after the x as well since `Intersect` works with two `IEnumerables`. Response has been updated

Answer (score 0):

A way of achieve that is use the Damerau-Levenshtein algorithm. This an algorithm that basically calculates how many changes would take to one string becomes equals to another, it can be implemented manually but it's kinda tricky and there is already a library ([SoftWx.Match](https://github.com/softwx/SoftWx.Match)) that encapsulates the logic for you.

SoftWx.Match has a static method called `DamerauOSA(string value1, string value2)` that returns a `double` between 0 and 1 telling how like the two strings are, mixing this with LINQ you can easily.

```
List<string> products = new List<string>()
{
    "product 1 max",
    "product 1 min"
};
var stringToCompare = "product min";

products.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Item {x} against {stringToCompare} has {Similarity.DamerauOSA(x, stringToCompare)} points of similarity"));

// 0.80 is an arbitrary number of how much "equality" you want from both strings
var filtered = products.Where(x => Similarity.DamerauOSA(x, stringToCompare) > 0.80).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Filtered");
filtered.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TqTmbh)